# DLookup with Multiple Criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access DB that has the following tables:

•   'Legal Entity Info' with [LegEntID] and [LegEntName]

•   'Policy Info' with [PolicyID] and [PolicyCarrierName]

•   'Policy Period' with [PolicyPeriodID] and [PolicyPeriod]

•   'Retention Amounts by Legal Entity' with [RetentionID], [PolicyPeriodID], [PolicyID], [LegEntID] and [RetentionAmount]

I have a form (Retention Payment Info Form), that pulls in the [PolicyPeriodID], [PolicyID], and [LegEntID] that are connected with a specific claim.  I need to pull in the correct [RetentionAmount] that corresponds to the match in the 'Retention Amounts by Legal Entity' table.  All three criteria ([PolicyPeriodID], [PolicyID], and [LegEntID]) have to be TRUE in order to pull in the correct [RetentionAmount].

On this form, I have an unbound field to show the [RetentionAmount] and I’m trying to write a DLookup function to select the [RetentionAmount] based on the selections on the form.  Here is what I think it should look like, however, it’s not working.

```
=DLookUp("[RetentionAmount]", 
    "Retention Amounts by Legal Entity", 
    "[PolicyPeriodID]='" &  Forms![Retention Payment Info Form].Form.[PolicyPeriodID] & 
    "' AND [PolicyID]='" &  Forms![Retention Payment Info Form].Form.[PolicyID] & 
    "' AND [LegEntID]='" &  Forms![Retention Payment Info Form].Form.[LegEntID] & 
    "'")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can replace `.Form.` by `!` in all 3 expressions, but that shouldn't make a difference. If these IDs are numbers, remove the single quotes. Else: please clarify *"it’s not working."*.

Comment: All three IDs are numbers, so I removed the single quotes.  That didn't change anything.  I then replaced the.Form with !, and it is now working.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`.Form` is only needed when working with subforms.

http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm is a good reference.
(You are here: `Forms!Mainform!ControlName`)

Correct syntax:

```
=DLookUp("[RetentionAmount]", 
    "Retention Amounts by Legal Entity", 
    "[PolicyPeriodID]=" & Forms![Retention Payment Info Form]![PolicyPeriodID] & 
    " AND [PolicyID]=" & Forms![Retention Payment Info Form]![PolicyID] & 
    " AND [LegEntID]=" & Forms![Retention Payment Info Form]![LegEntID])
```